# como recibir datos en el cliente (python) desde el servidor (nodejs) usando websocket

Tags: python, nodejs, socket.io, websocket

Actualmente estoy enviando los datos del servidor de la siguiente manera

```
this.socket.send('playback', Id, playbackData)
```

donde la 'playback' es el nombre del evento y los otros son los datos enviados desde el servidor

La pregunta es **¿Cómo recibo y manipulo estos datos en el lado del cliente que está en python?**
gracias de antemano a quien me pueda ayudar.

Comment: Estás en Stack Overflow *en español*. Podrías traducir tu pregunta o eliminarla y preguntar en el sitio en inglés por favor? De lo contrario, terminará cerrada y sin respuestas.

Comment: No se mucho del tema, pero el modulo [socket](https://docs.python.org/es/3/library/socket.html) podría serte util.

Comment: vale, muchas gracias. voy a revisar tu sugerencia.

Comment: De nada linkon c: